# 404 Error on Google Sheets API from HTTP Request

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, httprequest

I am trying to append some data to a Google Sheets spreadsheet using a HTML POST Request. I am having some difficulty in solving the 404 error I get when sending the request. My request code is shown below:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    alert(httpRequest.status);
  }
}

var params = {
  "values": [
     [
       "value1",
       "value2"
     ]
  ]
}

httpRequest.open('POST', 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + spreadsheetID + 'values/Sheet1!B2:L2:append', true)
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

I have gained the necessary permissions in the access token, since I am able to create sheets, but I think there might be an issue with my url. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation [sheets.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

> https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}:append

I think you are missing a / before values

```
'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' + spreadsheetID + '/values/Sheet1!B2:L2:append', true)
```

Try testing it using the Try this api on the documentation page [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)